# Are there any angularjs directives for validating forms not using ng-model?

Tags: angularjs, validation

The forms I am working with are not my own and therefore do not have ng-model on the inputs.  Is there a way or a directive that you would recommend that can provide basic validation(required,url,email) similar to the ng-model validation?

I know I can use jquery/pure js just wondering if there's an easy way with NG.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Did you try http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/validate

Comment: Thanks for the tip but that requires me adding ng-model="something" to the <input> as well.

Comment: Without `ng-model`, which way would you like to get the validation result?

Comment: If you are using a form, there should be a property on the scope which has the same name of the form (e.g. `scope.formName`). I notice there is `scope.formName.$setValidity(errorCode, isValid)`. You could try hooking in to that?